# How to get data's property value after axios.get call?

Tags: vue.js, axios

It's Vue.js app and the code looks as following:

```
getQrCodeUrl(paymentId) {
  this.$axios.get(`${this.$config.server}/api/crm/payments/qr/${paymentId}/url`)
  .then(responseUrl => {
    console.log('responseUrl.data =', responseUrl.data)
    console.log('responseUrl.data.url =', responseUrl.data.url)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    ...
  })
},
```

I've got responseUrl.data, but responseUrl.data.url is undefined as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows you that `responseUrl` is an object with `result` and `data` properties. I believe it is the successful promise. By adding a `.then(response => response.json())`, you will have the data by itself as a JSON object.

Refactor the code as follows :-

```
getQrCodeUrl(paymentId) {
  this.$axios.get(`${this.$config.server}/api/crm/payments/qr/${paymentId}/url`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response.url =', response.url)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      ...
    })
},
```